# Add css background-image to fluidPage sidebarPanel in R Shiny

Tags: html, css, r, shiny

I am trying to add an image background for the headerPanel in my r shiny fluidpage. It turns out to be more difficult than I anticipated. Advice would be appreciated.

My ui.R:

```
fluidPage(
  theme = "style.css",

  headerPanel(
    title = 'Department Name'
    ),

  sidebarPanel(
    # Code not shown
    ),

  mainPanel(
    tabsetPanel(
   # Code not shown
  )
 )
)
```

My style.css (which is stored under www sub-folder, the image department.png is also stored in www)

```css
@import url("//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway|Cabin:400,700");


h1 {
  background-image: url(department.PNG) no-repeat 0 0;
  font-family: 'Raleway';
  font-weight: 500;
  line-height: 1.1;
  position: relative;
}

body {
  background-color: #fff;
}
```

When I Run App, my fluidPage would load perfectly for everything, except the png image. I ctrl+U to check the HTML, and could not see png in there either. I am not sure what is missing.

Read other suggestions such as: https://community.rstudio.com/t/using-image-as-full-background-of-headerpanel-in-shiny-app/28601/2  , but found that using this method the image really disrupt the fluidpage layout.

Thank you very much in advance for your help!

Comment: Did you try `url("department.png")`

Comment: @Sada93 I did. No luck...

Comment: Try this? `background-image: url('/department.PNG') no-repeat 0 0;` or `background-image: url('department.PNG') no-repeat 0 0;`

Comment: @EGC, just did - no luck...

Comment: Too much to ask for a screenshot of your project structure? It might help